# Regex is not working as expected when you have tree patterns

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I have this regex:

```
^(?'IF'[IF\s]{3})(?'CONDICTION'[\w\s\d+=/\.\*-><\(\)]+)(?'THEN'THEN)(?'TRUE'[\w\s\d+=/\.\*-><\(\)]*)(?'ELSE'[\s\w]ELSE[\s|\n])(?<FALSE>[\w\s\d.+\-*/]*)(?<ENDIF>([\s\nENDIF]{6}))
```

For this expression:

```
IF 1 = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 3 ENDIF
```

Works fine, i got this groups:

```
IF: IF
CONDICTION: 1 = 1 
THEN: THEN
TRUE: 1
ELSE: ELSE 
FALSE: 3
ENDIF: ENDIF
```

But if I try this expression:

```
IF 1 = 1 THEN 1 ELSE IF 1 = 2 THEN 3 ELSE 2 ENDIF ENDIF
```

I got this groups:

```
IF: IF 
CONDICTION: 1 = 1 THEN 1 ELSE IF 1 = 2 
THEN: THEN
TRUE:  3
ELSE:  ELSE 
FALSE: 2 ENDIF
ENDIF:  ENDIF
```

But I want this:

```
IF: IF 
CONDICTION: 1 = 1
THEN: THEN
TRUE:  1
ELSE:  ELSE 
FALSE: IF 1 = 2 THEN 3 ELSE 2 ENDIF
ENDIF:  ENDIF
```

What regex I need to match this?

Comment: It doesn't work for "tree patterns" because this requires an actual syntactic parse tree which regexes were never meant to do. What you want is a parser, not a regex.

Comment: Chris is right. Regular expressions are called that because they are best at matching "regular" languages. You are trying to match a "context free" language, not a "regular" language. Build yourself a recursive-descent parser to match that language.

Comment: I would use Irony to be my grammar, but I want solve this using regex.

Comment: First: Think good about `[IF\s]{3}` and `[\s\nENDIF]{6}` - I'm sure you didn't wrote what you meant there (by the way, is `FFF` a valid condition? just asking...) Next - it *is* possible for .Net regular expressions to parse your language, but it can get somewhat complicated. Consider a few points: 1. String literals that may have words that look like conditions 2. Comments 3. Optional `ELSE` clauses. If you are really ready to tackle all of these problems, you can look into Balancing Groups. (I *might* give it a go later)

Comment: Only FFF is not a valid condition, but there is another guy the know it.
FFF > 3 is a valid condition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem using [Irony](http://irony.codeplex.com/)

I will explain details in blog and will edit this answer!

Answer (score 0):

You seem that you are on the right track. You have your grammar defined so you need to tokenize your expressions and depending on your grammar parse them. In other words you need to write a parser for your particular needs.

Some useful link :

http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/110782-c-beginner-parser-class-tutorial/